# FireBug - TypeError: item is undefined

Tags: jquery, firebug, drop-down-menu, jquery-chosen

I am using the Chosen Select Box Jquery plugin in my site. The options in the select get updated with ajax so when you select something in 1 box the options for the next box show up.

I've almost got it working but when i click the second box option the third boxes options dont show up. I get an error in FireBug saying:

TypeError: item is undefined

item.selected = true;

It says it is in the Chosen Box's js file.

JS =======================

```
 Chosen.prototype.result_select = function(evt) {
  var high, high_id, item, position;
  if (this.result_highlight) {
    high = this.result_highlight;
    high_id = high.attr("id");
    this.result_clear_highlight();
    if (this.is_multiple) {
      this.result_deactivate(high);
    } else {
      this.search_results.find(".result-selected").removeClass("result-selected");
      this.result_single_selected = high;
      this.selected_item.removeClass("chzn-default");
    }
    high.addClass("result-selected");
    position = high_id.substr(high_id.lastIndexOf("_") + 1);
    item = this.results_data[position];
    item.selected = true;                                <---------- Error
    this.form_field.options[item.options_index].selected = true;
    if (this.is_multiple) {
      this.choice_build(item);
    } else {
      this.selected_item.find("span").first().text(item.text);
      if (this.allow_single_deselect) this.single_deselect_control_build();
    }
    if (!(evt.metaKey && this.is_multiple)) this.results_hide();
    this.search_field.val("");
    if (this.is_multiple || this.form_field_jq.val() !== this.current_value) {
      this.form_field_jq.trigger("change", {
        'selected': this.form_field.options[item.options_index].value
      });
    }
    this.current_value = this.form_field_jq.val();
    return this.search_field_scale();
  }
};
```

I've spent hours trying to figure it out but can't. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you certain that `results_data` is not empty? If it is, does it have a value in the result of `high_id.substr(high_id.lastIndexOf("_") + 1)`?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum i was just trying something out before.

Comment: @Oded i hope this doesnt sound like a dumb question but how would i check if its empty or not. Cause i think it is at the time the page is loaded, but not later

Comment: what is the output of alert(this.results_data); ? (just before the problematic line)

Comment: [object Object],[object Object] is what the popup says

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had the same problem, add an empty option tag in your select HTML, should work fine.

Edit: As [knuturO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3232242/knuturo) pointed out, arrays are 0 indexed, but most chosen indexes start at 1. By adding an empty value, there no longer is a mismatch between array indexing and the chosen indexes. A dropdown for example works the same way.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not working on this project anymore. Which is disappointing because I never did get it to work and ended up not being able to use Chosen. Glad you were able to fix it though.

Comment: I'm not sure my solution, solves your exact problem, but it never hurts to try, maybe you'll get around to it :)

Comment: this soulution worked for me. This is off by one problem since arrays start at 0 and chosen index starts at 1. By adding a item with value='' and text='' it will not be shown but will exist in the array fixing the off by one error.